# In Peeved Penguin how do I add properties to the Seal object

Tags: objective-c, class, properties, cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder

In the last weeks I have been trying to use cocos on my Mac.  In the process I have brought my mac up to Yosemite, have the current version of XCode, and the most current version of cocos, and the same for SpriteBuilder.  Though an experienced programmer, I am not proficient in Objective-C.

I have managed to get the Peeved Penguin project working and now am trying to modify it.

I want to be able to add properties and methods to an object.  Below is where I am at in my development process:

Code:

Seal.h

```
#import "CCSprite.h"

@interface Seal : CCSprite

@property int SealNbr;

- (void) TestHi;

@end
```

Seal.m

```
#import "Seal.h"

@implementation Seal

@synthesize SealNbr;

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        SealNbr = 4;
        CCLOG(@"Seal %i created", SealNbr);
//        CCLOG(@"Seal %@ created", self.initWithImageNamed);

        CCLOG(@"Seal-1 at %f, %f", self.position.x, self.position.y );
        self.position = ccp(450.f, 280.f);
        CCLOG(@"Seal-2 at %f, %f", self.position.x, self.position.y );

    }
    return self;
}

- (void) TestHi
{
    CCLOG(@"Hi to seal %i", SealNbr );
}
@end
```

Main.m

```
CCLOG(@"RunRace Loaded");

CCNode *_Seal =  [CCBReader load:@"Seal" ];
_Seal = [CCBReader load:@"Seal" ];

CCLOG(@"Name: %@", _Seal.name);
CCLOG(@"Seal at %f, %f", _Seal.position.x, _Seal.position.y );


// - A  _Seal.SealNbr = 5;
// - B  [_Seal TestHi ];
```

Results

```
2014-10-24 07:05:44.093 TrackTest2[22988:1782919] RunRace Loaded
2014-10-24 07:05:44.093 TrackTest2[22988:1782919] Seal 4 created
2014-10-24 07:05:44.094 TrackTest2[22988:1782919] Seal-1 at 0.000000, 0.000000
2014-10-24 07:05:44.094 TrackTest2[22988:1782919] Seal-2 at 450.000000, 280.000000
2014-10-24 07:05:44.139 TrackTest2[22988:1782919] Name: 
2014-10-24 07:05:44.140 TrackTest2[22988:1782919] Seal at 0.000000, 0.000000
```

Notice that the property name is not getting displayed.  I set the Seals name to "Frosty" at SpriteBuilder time.  Not sure how to get that to work.

The big issue happens when I try uncommenting the lines labled // - A and // - B, so that I can access the property SealNbr and use the method TryHi, I get the error messages:

Error Message:

```
Property 'SealNbr' not found on object of type 'CCNode *'

Property 'TestHi' not found on object of type 'CCNode *'
```

One other question along this line is how to I change the image file at run time instead of SpriteBuilder time?

BTW, user Aeisys asked a very similiar question inn August that was answered by DrBeardface.  When I try the cast mentioned in the respose, I get the same error except this time it is on the cast.

Moded code:

```
Seal *_Seal =  (Seal *)[CCBReader load:@"Seal" ];
```

Error:

```
Use of undeclared identifier 'Seal'
```

Comment: Just found what to do.  I added the line #import "Seal.h" to main.m and it now works.

Answer (score 0):

Found out that adding

"import seal.h"

in main.m solves the problem.

It should have been obvious, but then, who sees the obvious?

Thanks